# Is it possible to preview a LaTeX code on Notepad++ (HTML Preview extension)?

Tags: javascript, html, notepad++, mathjax

It is possible to preview this LaTeX code on just by saving it  as HTML and opening it on Firefox. In other words, I want the notepad ++ to "read/render" the code just as other browsers do. What do I need to do to make this possible? I researched, but all I found was some batch function that calls sumatraPDF.

I asume that as firefox is able to render the code, then the "HTML preview" extension would be also able, is that right?

Here is a simple code with some equations:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">                
    </script>
    <title>tex texample</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>$$\frac{1}{a} &lt; \frac{1}{b}$$</p>
    <p>$$\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 = \frac{(n^2+n)(2n+1)}{6}$$</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

All i get is a equation. I wish i could get that preview on Notepad++ preview HTML extension. Is it possible? 
Thank you.

[equation rendered on firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mXMi.png)

Edit: actually I found this guy approach to deal with this, he wrote that using "doxygen" is possible to make it, however I didn't manage to make the Jscript and Cscript part.

http://csholmq.se/blog/notepadpp

I appreciate other kind of solutions, or some other that could give some understanding on what is needed to do there.

Comment: Random guess: [update the MathJax URL](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/start.html#using-a-content-delivery-network-cdn)  since the old CDN has been retired.

Comment: it still won't render the math codes

Comment: i think you were right, i had an old code trying to render, but still, it renders on firefox somehow, but not on notepad++!! brutal

Comment: Strange. There might be unexpected limitations in this kind of embedded-IE that prevent MathJax from working. Have you tried switching to the SVG output? (replace `HTMLorMML` with `SVG` in `config` part of the url).

Comment: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.2/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML

this config works on both firefox and notepad++, you were right, thanks

Comment: Can I ask one more thing? I wanted to get a PDF that way(directly from my notepad++) can you give me a hint on how i can do this?

Comment: The natural way would be to print to PDF but I'm afraid I don't know if such embedded-IE frames can print. Maybe the maintainer of that preview plugin knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time has moved on and now it would be fairly easy to script previewing the HTML in IExplorer with print to PDF preview.

[image]

**We can do similar with MS Edge**

```
start msedge.exe file:///C:/Users/your/Documents/SomeMath.html
```

[image]

And I tried to script print it --headless to PDF but did not succeed

[image]

Thus I suggest the best native method in windows is in notepad++ use a script opening the html in IE / Edge or FF, then a second script call the CTRL+P function to print to PDF.

so a vbs script something like this should do

```
DIM shell
SET shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Shell.Run "cmd /c start msedge.exe file:///C:/Users/wherever/Documents/SomeMath.html"
WScript.Sleep(5000)
Shell.SendKeys "^P"
```

[image]

[image]